# jQuery.grep changes original array

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery.grep() documentation clearly states that the process does **not** change the grepped array.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

The following code finds a matching value from what I hope is an original, persistent array - arrLibrary.

I then modify the resulting commentObj...but the changes I make to it flow back into arrLibrary. Which I guess is not contradicting the jQuery documentation of GREP: we do create a new array, a subset of the original, but it still refers to the original and so changes made to it flow back to the original?

What am I missing? How do I get a subset of an array **and then update data in it** without messing up the original?

```
  var commentObj = [];   //  Will hold the updated object for inserting into page and saving to DB
  //  FIRST, find full object from arrLibrary

  if (source !== "chrome_logged"){
    commentObj = $.grep(arrLibrary, function(commie){ // just use arr
      return commie.uniqueID === obj.comment_id;
    });
    commentObj = commentObj[0];
  } else {
    commentObj = obj;   //  Just use what was passed
  }
```

Later in my code I update commentObj.fieldwhatever = "this sucks" and the matching key/value in arrLibrary updates to match.

Any help/direction appreciated.

Comment: Which exact jQuery version do you use?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! 3.4.1. I think I understand what's going on (see my answer below)...but now wonder if there isn't a better way to get a subset of an array AND THEN extend/edit the data in that subset.

Answer (score 0):

This seems crazy to me...but I understand...even though grep doesn't alter the original array - it results in a subset if there is a match - the resulting subset of data **is still referring** to the original.

So if you update the resulting array the original changes, too.

So I've done a deep copy to break the connection to the original...

```
var commentObj1 = [];   //  temp array - subset of arrLibrary...will still be connected to arrLibrary - reference
  //  FIRST, find full object from arrLibrary
  if (source !== "chrome_logged"){
    commentObj1 = $.grep(arrLibrary, function(commie){ // just use arr
      return commie.uniqueID === obj.comment_id;
    });
    commentObj1 = commentObj1[0];
  } else {
    commentObj1 = obj;   //  Just use what was passed
  }

  var commentObj = $.extend(true, {}, commentObj1); // deep copy - break reference to arrLibrary
```